# error: cannot convert 'void (CApp::*)()' to 'void (*)()' for argument '1' to 'void Mix_HookMusicFinished(void (*)())'

Tags: c++, callback, sdl, pointer-to-member, sdl-mixer

I'm trying to create a C++ application using SDL and SDL_Mixer for audio, and am trying to follow [this](http://www.kekkai.org/roger/sdl/mixer/) tutorial. However, using SDL_Mixer's Mix_HookMusicFinished() isn't working, giving the error: argument of type 'void (CApp::)()' does not match 'void (*)()'

I've researched this error, and it seems the problem is that cleanMusic is a member function of CApp. I can't tell how to solve the problem, however, since most problems similar to this one are centered around pthread_create(). My cleanMusic() function needs to be able to access music_ which is a private variable of CApp. How can I resolve the error?

Here is the code for CApp.h, CApp::handleKeyEvents(), and CApp::cleanMusic(). Let me know if you need to see something else.

CApp.h

```
#ifndef CAPP_H
    #define CAPP_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>

#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>

class CApp {
    private:
        bool isRunning_;
    private:
        void cleanMusic();
    private:
        SDL_Surface *surfDisplay_;
        Mix_Music *music_;
        bool isRotating_;
        GLfloat rQuad_;
    public:
        CApp();
        int run();
    public:
        bool initialize();
        void handleEvents(SDL_Event *event);
        void loopData();
        void render();
        void clean();

    public:
        void handleKeyEvents(SDL_KeyboardEvent *key);
};

#endif // CAPP_H
```

CApp::handleKeyEvents()

```
#include "CApp.h"

void CApp::handleKeyEvents(SDL_KeyboardEvent *key) {
    switch(key->keysym.sym) {
        case SDLK_m:
            if (key->state == SDL_PRESSED) {
                if(music_ == NULL) {
                    music_ = Mix_LoadMUS("resources\\audio\\boop.wav");
                    Mix_PlayMusic(music_, 0);
                    Mix_HookMusicFinished(cleanMusic);

                    isRotating_ = true;
                } else {
                    Mix_HaltMusic();
                    cleanMusic();
                    isRotating_ = false;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

CApp::cleanMusic()

```
#include "CApp.h"

void CApp::cleanMusic() {
    Mix_FreeMusic(music_);
    music_ = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Apis that take `void(*)()` callbacks suck.

Answer (score 1):

Two changes. `cleanMusic` needs to be `static`.

```
static void cleanMusic();
```

Second, you register the hook with:

```
Mix_HookMusicFinished(&CApp::cleanMusic);
```

Since your method is now `static`, `music_` needs to be `static` as well.

```
static Mix_Music *music_;
```

This means that there will only be one instance of this variable shared between all instantiations of CApp. Since I haven't seen all of your code, I can't tell if this is an issue.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Now I'm getting the error: invalid use of member 'CApp::music_' in static member function.

Comment: Did you also update where the function is defined so that it is void static? It's actually three changes (2 are related).

Comment: I just updated the declaration because if I update the definition as well, I additionally get error: cannot declare member function 'static void CApp::cleanMusic()' to have static linkage [-fpermissive].

Comment: Sorry, you're quite right. It just goes in the class definition in the .h file. You can't/don't use it in the .cpp file for this purpose.

Comment: The reason for the error is that CApp::cleanMusic accesses non-static member music_.

Answer (score 0):

`void cleanMusic();` is what is known as a *member function*. A member function is **very different** from a normal function. The reason your compiler complains is because `Mix_HookMusicFinished` expects a normal function pointer of type `void (*)()`, but you are trying to pass a member function pointer of type `void (CApp::*)()`. These types are incompatible.

The simplest solution is just to make `cleanMusic` a normal function and `Mix_Music *music;` a global:

```
Mix_Music *music;

void cleanMusic() {
    Mix_FreeMusic(music);
    music = NULL;
}
```

Another way is to make them both `static` members:

```
static void cleanMusic();
static Mix_Music *music_;
```

Comment: Are global variables perfectly acceptable for an application such as a game then? I've read that they should be avoided, but I don't think I can avoid it in this case without breaking the rest of my code. Thank you!

Comment: @Qazplm123890: Instead of the global, use an anonymous namespace `namespace { Mix_Music *music; }`. This prevents the problems of globals by keeping the name local to the source file.